# Confusion about the proof of lemma 2.16 in Mendelson logic.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf)" by Elliot Mendelson , page 89. The lemma is this:

> Let **J** be a consistent, complete scapegoat theory. Then **J** has a model **M**
> whose domain is the set **D** of closed terms of **J**.

And here is the proof in the book:

[image]
[image]

What I don't understand is the induction . I am a high-school student who only knows about weak and strong induction . Because it says

> The proof of $(\square)$ is by induction on the number $r$ of connectives and quantifiers in $\mathscr C$. Assume that  $(\square)$ holds for all closed wfs with
> fewer than $r$ connectives and quantifiers.

I first thought this is strong induction . However , In strong induction , along with the inductive step (above) , we also have to prove some sort of base case (right?).But I was not able to see any mention of some base case or proving that base case. Maybe I am missing something important . Can someone tell me what that is ?

Comment: Case 1 in the picture is the case where $r=0$. Presumably that's what you meant by a base case.  (In general, strong induction doesn't explicitly involve a base case. For example, in the present proof, strong induction would require you to prove the result for $r=0$ assuming it for all $r<0$. Since $r<0$ never occurs, that amounts to proving the result for $r=0$ with no assumptions. You can call that a base case, but it's really just a special instance of the strong induction step.)

Comment: See [Structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: it's interesting that Mendelson is actually doing structural induction, but he says he's doing induction on the number of connectives and quantifiers. This seems to be quite common. I wonder why. Perhaps, it's just one less thing to explain.